# Set DropDownList default item

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Im using angular kendo DropDownList component like this:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist 
    [defaultItem]="customModel" 
    (valueChange)="modelValueChange($event)" 
    [data]="models" 
    [textField]="'name'" 
    [valueField]="'id'">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

on load DropDownList is setted to default item, on that DropDownList value change im populating template (predefined inputs), when i change that template predefined input i want that DropDownList component to be reseted or setted up to default item again.

Is it possible to do something like that?

**UPDATE: solution**

I added ngModel to component `[(ngModel)]="chosenModel"` so on every event used on predefined input i set `this.chosenModel = null` then kendo automatically set 
 dropdownlist to default option.

```
    <kendo-dropdownlist 
        [defaultItem]="customModel"
        [(ngModel)]="chosenModel" 
        (valueChange)="modelValueChange($event)" 
        [data]="models" 
        [textField]="'name'" 
        [valueField]="'id'">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>


predefinedInputValueChange(event: string): void {
    .
    .
    .

    this.chosenModel = null;//this will set kendo dropdownlist to default item
}
```

Comment: Probably `[placeholder]="Default value here"`

Comment: Could you please explain more, probably add more code.